# Play! JPA @ManyToMany bug

Tags: hibernate, jpa, playframework

I have three entities: *User*, *Team*, and *TeamInvite*.  Each *User* has one *Team*.  Each *User* can invite other *Users* to their *Team* by creating a *TeamInvite*.  When a *TeamInvite* is accepted, each *User's* *Team* is updated.  *TeamInvites* do not affect *Users*, just their *Teams*.

```
@Entity
public class Team extends Model {
    @OneToOne
    public User user;

    @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)   //I've also tried CascadeType.PERSIST
    public List<User> team = new ArrayList<User>();
}

@Entity
public class TeamInvite extends Model {
    @ManyToOne
    public User inviter;

    @ManyToOne
    public User invitee;

    public void fulfill() {
        Team team = Team.forUser(inviter);
        team.team.add(invitee);
        team.save();    //error gets thrown here

        team = Team.forUser(invitee);
        team.team.add(inviter);
        team.save();

        delete();
    }
}
```

When `TeamInvite.fulfill()` gets called, I get the following error:

```
PersistenceException occured : org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not insert collection: [models.Team.team#2]

play.exceptions.JavaExecutionException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not insert collection: [models.Team.team#2]
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:231)
    at Invocation.HTTP Request(Play!)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not insert collection: [models.Team.team#2]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1214)
    ...
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not insert collection: [models.Team.team#2]
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:92)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.recreate(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:1243)
    at org.hibernate.action.CollectionUpdateAction.execute(CollectionUpdateAction.java:81)
    ...
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Duplicate column name "TEAM_ID"; SQL statement:
insert into Team_dp_user (Team_id, team_id) values (?, ?) [42121-149]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:327)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:167)
    ...
```

I copied my annotation structure from the Yabe demo (Posts have a Set of Tags).  Anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the inverse side of `Team.team` relationship is named `User.team` as well. If so, you have a collision between columns names in the join table, because their default form is `propertyName + "_id"`.

So, you need to change one of the property names, or override default column names with [`@JoinTable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/JoinTable.html).

Comment: Changing Team.team to Team.members (which is probably a better name anyway) did in fact fix the problem.  Thanks!